# Cell is not recalculated after setting value in dependent cell

Tags: python, excel, pycel

I have this simple code:

```
excel = ExcelCompiler(filename=fname)

excel.evaluate('TEMP!C2')       # touch to be able to set
excel.set_value('TEMP!C2', 'SOMEVALUE')

print(excel.evaluate('TEMP!C2'))
print(excel.evaluate('TEMP!EN2'))
```

Cell `EN2` has a `CONCATENATE` formula with `C2` and some fixed cells. Problem is that is never recalcs the formula after setting the `C2` value.

Comment: Try refreshing the data. Or try this: Go to Files->Options->Formulas-> Calculation Options / Set Workbook calculation to Automatic. Also, check your formulas that they are not "Text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more fiddling, I found that `evaluate` creates the graph for calculating its value. So, I had the `evaluate` the formula cell:

```
excel = ExcelCompiler(filename=fname)

excel.evaluate('TEMP!EN2')
excel.set_value('TEMP!C2', 'SOMEVALUE')

print(excel.evaluate('TEMP!C2'))
print(excel.evaluate('TEMP!EN2'))
```